# Are there hidden constraints in auto-layout

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

I have a complex layout that works perfectly. Now I want to overlay the existing layout with a view that is resizable with, say a 40 pixel margin, relative to the window. When I add a empty custom view to the content view, the constraint system goes haywire and says it cannot satisfy the constraints, and the results are quite random.

I add the view as:

```
    contentView.addSubview(customView)
    let dict = ["CustomView" : customView]
    let s1 = "|-(40)-[CustomView]-(40)-|"
    let s2 = "V:|-(40)-[CustomView]-(40)-|"
    let con1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: s1, options: [],
                                                    metrics: nil, views: dict as [String : Any])
    let con2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: s2, options: [],
                                                      metrics: nil, views: dict as [String : Any])
    viewLayout.append(contentsOf: con1)
    viewLayout.append(contentsOf: con2)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(viewLayout)
```

As far as I can tell, this view should add no additional constraints as to the size or shape of the underlying content view, but should simply be resized to the appropriate size. It would seem that must be some implicit constraint on the view preventing it from simply being sized or I am missing something fundamental about constraints.

Comment: viewLayout is an empty array prior to the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. I needed to uncheck the "Translates Mask into Constraints" checkbox for the custom view.